# Sub categories with extra field

Tags: categories, structure

I'm stuck on a problem with categories. I never worked with them before so maybe it's not as difficult a I think.

I need the following structure:

Type of company 1 (e.g. Bakery)
    -Bakery 1 + website
    -Bakery 2 + website
    -Bakery 3 + website

Type of company 2 (e.g. Supermarket)
    -Super 1 + website
    -Super 2 + website
    -Super 3 + website

So my parent categories only need 1 field (type of company)
and the children need 2 types of fields (url + company name)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just leave the URL field blank for parent categories.

In the template you could check if the the category is level two before outputting the URL field.

```
{% if category.level == 2 and category.categoryUrl %}
    {{ category.categoryUrl }}
{% endif %}
```